# Templated STL containers as argument to function in cython

Tags: python, cython

I have written a function in cython that will search a STL vector of strings for a given string and return true if it is found, false otherwise.  Performance is very important here! I would ideally like to have a templated function to do the same thing so I don't have to write a function for each data type.  I am sure this is possible but I don't know the cython syntax for templated functions.  (I know how to do it in c++)

```
from libcpp cimport bool
from libcpp.string cimport string
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref, preincrement as inc

cpdef bool is_in_vector(string a, vector[string] v):
    cdef vector[string].iterator it = v.begin()
    while it != v.end():
        if deref(it) == a:
            return True
        #Increment iterator
        inc(it)
    return False
```

Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: have you considered wrapping the C++ code with boost::python instead? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/python/doc/

Comment: Not really as I am doing everything in Python+Cython already.  I am not really all that interested in adding boost to the mix.  Besides, cython is otherwise awesome.

Comment: Did you try [fused type](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/fusedtypes.html)?

Comment: @CzarekTomczak - I'm pretty sure that is exactly what I was looking for - I didn't know the right thing to be searching for in cython docs as this is not a problem I have had before.  If you want to put an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Fused Types](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/fusedtypes.html).

Example:

```
cimport cython

ctypedef fused any:
    string
    cython.int

cpdef bool is_in_vector(string a, vector[any] v)
```

Or this way:

```
ctypedef fused vector_t:
    vector[string]
    vector[cython.int]

cpdef bool is_in_vector(string a, vector_t v)
```